# ajax валидация подмодели, asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, валидация

У меня настроена валидация, как сказано в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106135/6089217) сообщении.

Но у меня проблема.

У меня имеется модель:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual ManInfo ManInfo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Post { get; set; }
}
public class ManInfo
{
    // ...
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Можно ли каким-то образом навесить валидацию свойства **ManInfo**? Т.е. подмодели у основной модели. Там имеются атрибуты Required.

На данный момент валидация идет только по свойствам модели Employee, но не свойствам **ManInfo**.

Повесить атрибут **Required** на свойство **ManInfo** не могу - т.к. внутри имеются свойства, которые не обязательны к заполнению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен путем создания нового класса - **CreateEmployeeViewModel**, в которой указал все поля, которые необходимы для заполнения.

Также переработал представление под данную модель и в методе post-запроса произвожу генерацию нужной модели.

Думаю приводить код тут не нужно.